# Removing encoded date of mp4's metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, encode, mp4

I want to remove encoded data in mp4 file for test.
for this, I try to use library like mp4box, ffmpeg, AtomicParsley.
But I can't.
How can I remove an encoded date in metadata?
Is it impossible?

```
$ mediainfo xxxxx.mp4 

General
Complete name                            : xxxxx.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                                : 4.62 MiB
Duration                                 : 2 min 0 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 323 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Writing application                      : Lavf57.71.100

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2 min 0 s
Duration_LastFrame                       : -1 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 322 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.60 MiB (100%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 1904-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: What command did you try with ffmpeg?

Comment: I did as follow .    
```ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy new001.mp4```

Comment: I didn't look into it, but perhaps that's just the default value of what `mediainfo` displays if there is no `creation_time` metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks LordNeckbeard. You're right.
it just the default value of mediainfo.
the real values is emptied.

> I didn't look into it, but perhaps that's just the default value of
>   what mediainfo displays if there is no creation_time metadata.

Answer (score 0):

With `MP4Box`:

```
MP4Box.exe -time 0 -mtime 0 -keep-utc -add input.mp4 -new output.mp4
```